# Add multiple sections to WooCommerce tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add two different sections to the WooCommerce Admin Products tab. 
The following code works only when I **don't** use the `elseif()`, if I add this, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-settings.php on line 197
```

The code:

```
// Create a section on the Products tab
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_sections_products', 'myplugin_add_section');
    function myplugin_add_section( $sections ) {

        $sections['myplugin'] = __('My Plugin page', 'myplugin');
        $sections['mypluginlog'] = __('My plugin Log', 'myplugin');
        return $sections;

    }

// Add Settings
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_settings_products', 'myplugin_all_settings', 10, 2);
    function myplugin_all_settings( $settings, $current_section ) {
        if ($current_section == 'myplugin') {
        // do something
        }
        elseif($current_section == 'mypluginlog') {
        // do something else
        }
        else {
        return $settings;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return an array if the `if statement` is true as `woocommerce_get_settings_` expecting an array as return.

so your code should be like this:

```
// Create a section on the Products tab
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sections_products', 'myplugin_add_section');
function myplugin_add_section($sections)
{

    $sections['myplugin'] = __('My Plugin page', 'myplugin');
    $sections['mypluginlog'] = __('My plugin Log', 'myplugin');
    return $sections;

}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_settings_products', 'myplugin_all_settings', 10, 2);
function myplugin_all_settings($settings, $current_section)
{

    if ($current_section == 'myplugin') {
        $my_settings = array();

        return $my_settings;


    } elseif ($current_section == 'mypluginlog') {
        $my_settings = array();

        return $my_settings;
    } else {
        return $settings;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/#)